# How to prove that adjacency matrix is L.I. if a graph contains no cycles?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

> Consider the vector space $F_n^2$ , and, as usual, let $e_i$ denote
>   the vector with 1 at the $i$th coordinate, and 0 at all others. Call a
>   vector of the type $e_i + e_j$ an edge vector, (think of it as
>   characterizing the edge between i and j in the graph on the vertex set
>   ${1, 2, \dots, n}$. Let $W$ be the $n−1$ dimensional subspace of
>   vectors whose coordinates sum to 0. Let $B$ be a set of edge vectors.
>   **Prove**: The set $B$ is linearly independent iff the corresponding
>   edges create a graph with no cycles.

I have tried to prove this but what about this case when we a graph triangle (Edges: ${(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)}$.

It's adjacency matrix will be:
$A = \begin{matrix}0 1 1\\1 0 1 \\ 1 1 0\end{matrix}$, which is L.I.

So, my question is: do I understand this question correctly? If yes, then why this example with a cycle has L.I. adjacency matrix?

**Note**: L.I. stands for Linearly Independent

Answer (score 3):

A set of columns of the *incidence matrix* are linearly independent if and only the corresponding edges form an acyclic graph. The rows and columns of the adjacency matrix are indexed by vertices.

Comment: Where could we find any proof for the incidence matrix statement?